# how to replace the each column name in a data-set, where it contains 500 columns using 'columns.str.replace'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

how to replace the each column name in a data-set where it contains 500 columns using `columns.str.replace` ?

This could only replace the column names given. What about 500 columns?

```
employee.rename(columns = {'Name': 'Name', 'Position': 'Job', 'Office': 'Company', 'Age': 'Years_Old', 'Start Date': 'S_Date', 'Salary': 'Remuneration'}, inplace = True)

employee.head()
```

Comment: if you want to replace a specific column you will always need a key and a value. If you don't want it you can use df.columns=['names of your columns']

Comment: you could pass columns into a list `col_ = df.columns.tolist()` then create a dict of it on it self using zip `dict(zip(col_,col_))` then edit your desired columns by iterating over the keys, you could then pass the values into the column names. feels like over-kill but I've done it before for very long dataframe's like yours.

Comment: @Pavan Being  If you can show some example about what kind of replacement you are looking, then it would help to write a solution for it.